# jquery toggel active and inactive work only first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-on

I want active and inactive users in the table. I want send a ajax request for same method. First i want to toggel active and inactive class in same anchor tag. I do that first.

This is html

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Dinuka Perera</td>
        <td>User is active</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="inactive">Activate</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Thilanga Perera</td>
        <td>User is inactive</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="active">Dectivate</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Test Perera</td>
        <td>User is active</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="inactive">Activate</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

js

```
$('.active').on('click', function () {
    $(this).html('Activate');
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('inactive');
});

$('.inactive').on('click', function () {
    $(this).html('Deactivate');
    $(this).removeClass('inactive');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

I did it earlier using `live()` function. But now jquery remove live function. So i used `on()`. But it is just working only for first time. What is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are chaging element class dynamically, You should use event delegation. Try this:

```
$(document).on('click','.active', function () {
    $(this).html('Activate');
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('inactive');
});

$(document).on('click','.inactive', function () {
    $(this).html('Deactivate');
    $(this).removeClass('inactive');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

**NOTE:** Instead of `document` use your `table id/class` to increase performance.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VW2d9/)**

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work

Add 'toggle' class

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Dinuka Perera</td>
        <td>User is active</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="toggle inactive">Activate</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Thilanga Perera</td>
        <td>User is inactive</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="toggle active">Dectivate</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Test Perera</td>
        <td>User is active</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="toggle inactive">Activate</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

With JavaScript

```
$(".toggle").click(function () {
    if($(this).hasClass("inactive")){
        $(this).html('Deactivate');
        $(this).removeClass('inactive');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
    else {
        $(this).html('Activate');
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('inactive');
    }
});
```

[Give it a go](http://jsfiddle.net/WUL4c/)